# Form File-Upload from URL or Data-URL?

Tags: forms, url, upload, greasemonkey

Can I use an `<input type="file">` field with an (data)URL?

I would need something like this in an Greasemonkey-script, but it seems impossible.
Or is there some way?

The only working alternative seems at the moment trying to write a proxy, which replaces the file-field with an text-field for an URL, so the proxy can download the file, and submit the form. But this is too complicated in contrast to a Greasemonkey-script.

I want to add to some sites a "select a preset image" at the position of the filechooser.

As JavaScript cannot access the disk to save an image and then select it for uploading again, it would need to be done by data-URL's or something like this.

Comment: To clarify...  (1) This is for pages that already have an upload form?   (2) You wish to modify the form to have a button that automatically, or effectively replaces the file with a fixed file of your choosing?   Is this correct?  Please clarify the question, **link to a target page**, and/or provide a step-by-step example.

Comment: the page has a file-upload form. think of a simple <form> with a file-field. now i want to automate the upload, not from local file but from url and/or fixed data (which could be retrieved i.e ia xmlhttprpc in greasemonkey).

so the question is, how can a file-upload server-side script be used with fixed data instead of file-field. best would be to have something like a hidden-input filled with the data, but then its not sent like a file-field (with filename and encoded data)